# Azure Functions: Autoscale is currently not available for this resource

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm running Azure Function with App Service B1 plan. When I want to manually scale it by going to "Scale Out" setting, I'm getting "Autoscale is currently not available for this resource." error, even though B1 plan supports only manual scale.

This used to work previously, as I could manually scale up to 3 instances. The only thing that has changes is that I added 1 more App Service plan to the same resource group...not sure if that could be the problem.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Yes, just seen this too. 
I am assuming that they have broken this in the portal.

Comment: Switching to Standard plan mitigates the issue, for a slightly higher cost though. I've also checked B3 plan, and scaling doesn't work there neither for me. Could it be region specific? Although I imagine that since standard plan works, it is probably not the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the portal. The bug fix for this is already planned for. Don't have a tentative date right now on the release of the bug fix.

Comment: is there a link to the bug in your issue tracker so we can monitor when it will be fixed? I assume we can still scale out using Powershell or other means, right?